# Can't access items in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, undefined

My array is:

```
{
"data":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAYAAACadoJwAAAgAElEQ…ACCCCAAAIIIICAvwIEIP760zoCCCCAAAIIIIAAAoES+P992sgQ2E6rdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
"name":"splash.png",
"imageOriginalWidth":1024,
"imageOriginalHeight":768,
"imageWidth":1969,
"imageHeight":1477,
"width":800,
"height":600,
"left":-585,
"top":-406
}
```

and I have two variables:

```
$image_data = $array['data'];
$image_name = $array['name'];
```

Both of these variables return `undefined`

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Aren't javaScript arrays created with `var foo = ["bar", 9, false]` ?

Comment: This isn't an array, it's an object literal.

Comment: Uh huh, except object literal has `var foo = {...}`

Comment: Is there a possibility that you don't assign the object to `$array`

Comment: Regarding your update, what is the value of `data` and `name`? Why are you declaring `$object_keys`? I think reading the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) will actually be the most helpful to you. However, `$image_data = $array['data'];` **will work** if `$array` has the value you claim it to have.

Comment: Note that you should, in the strict sense, declare your **var** names at the start of a function.  When you use _undeclared_ vars they are available globally, which will often lead to unwanted side effects, variable shadowing etc, etc.

Comment: @FelixKling - I'd argue that this is not a duplicate, since the question outlines a common misconception about what an array / object is.  Since early on, new users will hear that *An Array is an Object*, and so on.  In the utilitarian sense an Array is not an Object (although of course it is... ) - Hopefully you will see (a) this misconception is easy to hold for a beginner, and (b) that common misunderstandings, are also useful question examples in SO.  It may seem a little meta, but as SO grows, it should cover things that people get wrong, often.

Comment: @RipzCurlz invite me to chat, your last question edit is now veering you away from a valid SO question. `$('input[name=promo_image_1_values]').val();` is introducing an unknown value.

Comment: @Slomojo how do I invite you to chat?

Comment: @RipzCurlz - visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76403/js-objects-and-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it's important to note that this is not an array, it's an object definition.

An array can be defined as:

```
[
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAYAAACadoJwAAAgAElEQ…ACCCCAAAIIIICAvwIEIP760zoCCCCAAAIIIIAAAoES+P992sgQ2E6rdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
"splash.png",
1024,
768,
1969,
1477,
800,
600,
-585,
-406
]
```

Which is doesn't the keys, like `"data":` (which can also be expressed as `data:`) It seems you definitely want to access values by key, so what you really want is:

```
var data, name, myObject;

// NOTE: We do not "quote" object keys under normal circumstances.
myObject = {
    data:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAYAAACadoJwAAAgAElEQ…ACCCCAAAIIIICAvwIEIP760zoCCCCAAAIIIIAAAoES+P992sgQ2E6rdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
    name:"splash.png",
    imageOriginalWidth:1024,
    imageOriginalHeight:768,
    imageWidth:1969,
    imageHeight:1477,
    width:800,
    height:600,
    left:-585,
    top:-406
}

data = myObject["data"]; // We don't usuaully use this 
name = myObject["name"]; // style, although it works.
                         // 
                         // It's generally reserved for 
                         // dynamic access.
                         //
                         // i.e. we make a string to match the keyname.
```

However, to be correct you should use **dot syntax** to access the object key.

```
data = myObject.data;
name = myObject.name;
```

I hope this has cleared things up a little for you.

On a side note DO NOT use names like `$array`.  First don't use the `$` prefix for normal variables, this isn't PHP or BASIC.

Secondly, when you have an object, you want it to be named something that is useful / meaningful / memorable. (naming things is hard!)

When you name things properly, other people can read and understand your code, and after a heavy weekend on the town, so can you.

Comment: Thanks @Slomojo this has helped a lot as you may have guessed I am still learning.

I have gone with UnderscoreJS but it still returning undefined.

Comment: myObject[data] in your example is = myObject[undefined]. You did not define a value for data. The right approach would be to either initialize the data variable or use quotes myObject["data"] or myObject.data to access that property of the myObject. Other than that, good answer and information for the original question poster.

Comment: `myObject[data]` should be `myObject.data`. However, I don't see what you are doing vastly different from what the OP already does.

Comment: @Slomojo - I have added the actual code to my original question as it is still returning undefined. The image object is created by an image upload / cropping tool on a form.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried declaring the array and also the variables you wanna store the store the stuff from array to, using the var keyword?

E.g:

```
var myArray = ["hello",["world"];
```

By looking at your code I have the impression that you were trying to make a custom object.

Comment: Your array definition isn't syntactically correct.

Comment: Also, we should strive to use the correct language when referring to object structures like the one shown in the question which is referred to as an object literal.